# Timer doesn't tick

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, timer

Today I've tried Visual Studio + WinForms (I've been using Xamarin)
I dont use designer, just create empty project and link needed libraries.
So, my timer doesn't work properly, it ticks only in minimized form.

App.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Line
{
    class App
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Window());
        }
    }
}
```

Window.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Line
{
    class Window : Form
    {
        Timer timer;
        PictureBox pictureBox;
        Bitmap bmp;

        public struct Circle
        {
            public PointF position;
            public SizeF size;
        };

        List<Circle> circles;

        public Window()
        {
            this.Text = "Line";
            this.Size = SizeFromClientSize(new Size(640, 480));
            pictureBox = new PictureBox();
            pictureBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pictureBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            pictureBox.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(pictureBox_Paint);
            this.Controls.Add(pictureBox);
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Window_Load);
            this.Resize += new EventHandler(Window_Resize);
            circles = new List<Circle>();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 15;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        }

        private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            foreach (Circle c in circles)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(Pens.White, new RectangleF(c.position, c.size));
            }
            pictureBox.Image = bmp;
        }

        private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Circle c;
            Console.WriteLine("Works");
            for (int i = 0; i < circles.Count; i++)
            {
                c = circles[i];
                c.size.Width = (c.size.Width > 200) ? 100 : c.size.Width + 1;
                circles[i] = c;
            }
            pictureBox.Invalidate();
        }

        private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            circles.Add(new Circle());
            Circle c = circles[0];
            c.position = new PointF(100, 100);
            c.size = new SizeF(100, 100);
            circles[0] = c;
        }

        private void Window_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
            pictureBox.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Same code worked fine in Xamarin.

Comment: Why would you not use the designer? There's an entire partial class that gets created that you don't want to write yourself.

Comment: You're completely misusing `Paint`.  Draw on `e.Graphics`; don't use a `PictureBox` or `Image` or `Bitmap` at all.

Comment: I'm using Bitmap because PictureBox supports Double Buffer, and if i use just Graphics then there will be "flicks".

Comment: Your `Paint` routine is being called in an infinite loop and that blocks the main thread, the timer works always but as it uses the window message queue the messages aren't received.

Comment: I dont want to use designer, because it adds trash files in my clean project, it links useless libraries etc. I want to know what things are in my project.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,f67adf711ae5bec3 and go deeper in code, it will call Invalidate() soon.

Comment: I've commented all except lines needed for timer and it still doesn't tick.

Comment: You can turn on doublebuffering on any control by subclassing it or by reflection. You are also leaking resources. And the timer can't run that fast anyway. But those are minor problems..

Comment: Just commenting the `pictureBox_Paint` method content the timer starts working.

Answer (score 1):

1) in `timer_Tick` remove line: `pictureBox.Invalidate();`
2) cut code from `pictureBox_Paint` and paste at the end of `timer_Tick`
3) fix variable name collision `c`